# game built using Intel XDK

Tags: android, intel-xdk

My small (javascript html5 2D canvas game+ cordova) game run seem good on intel xdk simulator and intel app preview (connect with intel xdk app via wifi use "local apps" tab),

But after build to apk file, it run very slow animation on android 4.4 (samsung galaxy core prime).
I don't know why? Thank you for your help!

Comment: how can we know the reason without demo or preview ???

Comment: Thank you for your attention, it's just simple game, now i'm  trying to build on other tools, "Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova" could be appropriate for my game, run on android emulator is slow, but real device is ok.

Comment: games with phonegape are slow as Turtle because of phone gape has no support for webgl i suggest to use cocon.js or crosswalk and you will see the difference

Answer (score 1):

its because the preview is using the crosswalk webview... to get the same perfomance just build using crosswalk

Comment: As Amir states, you need to build for Crosswalk. The webview in Android <5.0 is very low performance. See [this blog](http://blogs.intel.com/evangelists/2014/09/02/html5-web-app-webview-app/) for some details. Also, [see this doc page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/dev-emulator) regarding limitations of the Emulate tab in the Intel XDK. It is _not_ a device, it is a simple simulation running on your desktop computer, there is a big difference in the performance of your desktop compared to mobile devices.

Comment: p.s. Use the Debug tab to preview your app on Crosswalk. When using App Preview with the Test tab your app runs in the native webview. When using App Preview with the Debug tab it runs in a Crosswalk webview.

Comment: Thank you, maybe CocoonJS is a one of good choices for building html5 canvas game to mobile.